# how to reduce doubly linked list complexity in the code

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

```
// Complete the sortedInsert function below.

/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * DoublyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     DoublyLinkedListNode next;
 *     DoublyLinkedListNode prev;
 * }
 *
 */
static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode head, int data) {
    DoublyLinkedListNode Leader=head;
    DoublyLinkedListNode newNode = new DoublyLinkedListNode(data);
    while(Leader.next!=null){

        if(data>Leader.data){
            Leader = Leader.next;
        } 
        else {
            if(Leader.prev == null) {
                newNode.next = Leader;
                Leader.prev = newNode;
                head = newNode;
                return head;
            } 
        }

    }
    if(Leader.next == null) {
        if(data<Leader.data) {
            newNode.prev = Leader.prev;
            newNode.next = Leader;
            Leader.prev.next = newNode;
            return head;
        } else {
            newNode.prev = Leader;
            Leader.next = newNode;
            return head;
        }


    }
       return head;



}
```

in the above-sorted insert method how to decrease this doubly linked list complexity, this is a hackerrank question I'm getting timed outs for the test cases I need help in decreasing the time complexity for this code.

Answer (score 0):

You code will never come out of while loop.

Lets take the example. List = [(1), (4), (4)](only 1 element). New node is (4). Your result should be [(1), (4), (4), (4)]. But lets walk your code and check what will happen. Initially Leader = (1)

```
while(Leader.next!=null){ // 1

    if(data>Leader.data){  // 3
        Leader = Leader.next;
    } 
    else { // 6
        if(Leader.prev == null) { // 7
            newNode.next = Leader;
            Leader.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            return head;
        } 
    }

}
```

At line 1 check will pass (as (1).next is not null; in fact it is (4)).

At line 3 ((4) > (1)). Check pass. Leader = (1).next = (4). Jump to line 1

At line 1 check will pass (as (4).next is not null; in fact it is (4)).

At line 3 ((4) > (4)). Check Fail. Enter line 7

At line 7 check will fail ((4).prev is not null; in fact it is (4) - 1st 4). No update in Leader will take place. Leader will remain same & you will enter infinte loop from here.

You will have to take care of this. Maybe the Problem's discussion page will help. But do give it a through try.

My own try is included below:

> ```
> static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(DoublyLinkedListNode head, int data) {
>         DoublyLinkedListNode n = new DoublyLinkedListNode();
>         n.data = data;
>         DoublyLinkedListNode curr = head;
>         if (head == null) {
>             return n;
>         }
>         // if given node is smaller than 1st node
>         if (data < curr.data) {
>             n.next = curr;
>             return n;
>         }
>         // find first node greater than given node
>         while (curr.next != null && curr.data < data) {
>             curr = curr.next;
>         }
>         // reached to the end.
>         if (curr.next == null && data >= curr.data) {
>             curr.next = n;
>         } else { // found the 1st node which is greater than given node
>             curr.prev.next = n;
>             n.next = curr;
>         }
>         return head;
>     }
> ```